# Can fragment start in new window in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a project and I'm using fragments. But I wanna open fragment in new windows like a pop-up, `startActivity`. Is this possible?

Comment: Check about [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to extract Activity context from you pop-up, and then use this context to proceed your fragment, an example:

```
Activity activity = (Activity)view.getContext();
activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace("yourContentId", fragment);
```

Comment: Can I set this when button click? Thanks for your reply

Comment: Hi again @ResolutioN When click button happens nothing?

Comment: Can you post your code so that I can help you investigate?

Comment: I'm setting items from json to fragment. That's OK nothing wrong. But I want to open fragment, when click button not after parsing. This is the my problem.